# Print receipt with thermal printer

Tags: vb.net, printing, pos, receipt

I want to print receipts with a thermal printer (Xprinter XP-Q800 Series) programatically using my software for a client who has a store.

The problem is that when I print the receipt it's blurry and the letters look like a points with spaces not one shape (I hope the problem is clear).

I tried to change the font but it give the same result for me.
When I save it as PDF, it's saved with good quality - the letters look better than the result when I print it using xprinter (here I think the issue is with the printdocument setting!)

My code is:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim tmpImg As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    Panel1.DrawToBitmap(tmpImg, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Panel1.Width, Me.Panel1.Height))
    'Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tmpImg)
    '    g.CopyFromScreen(Panel1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)), New Point(0, 0), New Size(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height))
    'End Using
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(tmpImg, 0, 0)
    Dim aPS As New PageSetupDialog
    aPS.Document = PrintDocument1


    'Dim bm As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
    'Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height))
    'e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0)
    'Dim aPS As New PageSetupDialog
    'aPS.Document = PrintDocument1
End Sub
Private Sub Guna2Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Guna2Button1.Click
    Try
        If Not GunaTextBox9.Text = "Print" Then
            PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = GunaTextBox9.Text
            PrintDocument1.Print()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using the low-resolution bitmap which is shown on the screen, you need to use the [Graphics.DrawString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring) to create the text at the correct resolution for the printer (see its documentation to get that value or the numbers to work it out from).

Comment: actually i dont know how to use it instead of bitmap !!

Comment: There is some code in [printing to thermal printer using vb.net from datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15643894/1115360) which may help to get you started in conjunction with the documentation for the [PrintDocument Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument). You will probably need to look at several documentation articles to piece together everything you need.